# Change JavaScript object values with auto-generated HTML form

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I have got a 'big' JavaScript object that looks somewhat like this:

```
var userConfig =  {   
      active: true,  
      subElement: { someProp: 156, otherProp: 'yaye' },  
      foo: ['bar', 'see', 'no']  
      // etc  
}
```

What I'm looking for is some sort of framework that I pass the variable (or a part of the variable) to and that reads all properties and creates a form where these can be configured. So a checkbox would be created for a boolean, a textbox for a string etc...

Anyone knows about such a library?

**Update**: At the moment settings are changed by opening the JS and editting the variables manually (The JS is a locally stored greasemonkey script). Pretty much anything beats that really.
I'm not interested in writing (alot of) code to do two way binding, creating all the UI widgets and having a clean seperation of concerns (MVVM, MVP, ...) which is what Knockout/Backbone/... does (judging from the tutorials).

**Instead**:

```
var userConfigUpdater = {
    active: { description: "Activates or deactivates feature X", editType: "boolean"},
    subElement: {
        description: "subElement",
        editType: "tabularItem",
        someProp: {description: "foo", editType: "text"},
        // more
    }
}
createHtmlWidgets(userConfig, userConfigUpdater);
```

Now the user can edit the form elements and then we have something like:
`$("#okButton").click(function() {userConfig = getUpdatedValues();});`

Granted, it doesn't look very nice, but it would get the job done quite fast/easily. I'm guessing there is not yet some public framework that does something like this?

Comment: depends how the UI looks, right? and the options. the `active: true` would probably be a check box but some other property like `active: { yes: 1, no: 0, notsure: -1 }` might make sense for a radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own 'framework'.

It is 'pretty' generic but somewhat integrated into the rest of my project, really limited in features and the API is not very clean. Use at your own risk :)

[The source code on GitHub](https://github.com/SanguPackage/Script/tree/master/page/settings/sangu). The 'framework' is `propui.js` and `sangu_config.js` is the configuration for propui.

Example how to call the API:

```
backgroundColor: {
    label: "Change the background color",
    propUI: {
        getter: function() { return settings.backgroundColor; },
        setter: function(value) { settings.backgroundColor = value; },
        editor: "bool"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I know is knockoutjs. This doesn't do exactly what you want but what it does do is allow a mechanism for keeping that object in the knockout world it would be called a viewModel in sync with your form so if you update the form contents it would update that object's data automatically and vice-versa

Comment: I have updated the initial question providing an example of what exactly I'm looking for. At the moment I _think_ that writing some functions like `function createBooleanWidget()` and `function updateBooleanWidget()` would still be faster than using knockoutjs.

Comment: Per your update: I know you said you want a quick and dirty solution but I really feel you should look into knockouts integration with jquery templates. I feel like you could achieve almost exactly what you want to do. Once you learn knockout the amount of code needed to do what you want to do will be trivial. I'm always hesitant to give dirty unclean answers on here since it might work in the "quick and dirty" sense but it does not grow a community which pushes for code that is clean, scalable and maintainable.

Comment: A bit late reply. I wasn't going to get back to this if/when I've written a solution. As for production code I agree. However, this is a Greasemonkey script so there are no scalability issues. Getting a framework such as knockoutjs to run within A) A single file and B) Within the Greasemonkey sandbox (while remaining compatible with Firefox, Opera and Chrome), ... is probably not so easy. And to what end? All I want to do is have the user be able to update JS variables without changing the values in the source with a text editor.